# Jplayer pausing yet restarting

Tags: html, jplayer

Having an issue with Jplayer,  Have set up a script function that when clicked should pause, but it automatically pauses and restarts immediately when clicked.   Is it because of the double id=mp3 tag on each track?  Because when I have inserted a number after the id and changed the $('#mp3') to be called $('#mp31') the pause no longer works.

```
    <tr><td>Tracklist:</td></tr>

<script>$('#mp3').click(function(){ $("#jp-player").jPlayer("pause"); return false;});</script>

<tr><td>1. </td><td><a href="mp31.mp3" id="mp3">Test</a>Friend</a> (Techno)</td></tr><tr><td>2. </td><td><a href="mp32.mp3" id="mp3">Test</a>Enemy</a> (Ambient)</td></tr>
```

Any help appreciated!

CP

Comment: Having two ids the same is invalid HTML and 'can' cause problems, you should definitely change that, although quite possibly not the cause.

Comment: I agree, oddly though when I create two instances of the script and call 1 mp31 and other mp32 it doesn't work?